# Ability to extend app with scripts

Tags: c#

Is it possible to make C# app use external scripts? Luke if i make shell application and i want to allow pepole add their own scripts (type command to add script from file and then execute it by command (example: 'calculator') I'll accept all ways to do this.

Comment: Not really afaik. C# is a compiled language. What __exactly__ do you want those scripts to achieve? You could try to create a 'small language'.. Or you could look into lua, __maybe__

Comment: I made an app that is shell. I want to execute scripts from a file and assign command to it.

Comment: @TaW That is incorrect. C# can execute code on the fly. You can compile C# into an assembly and then execute it (look at projects like [ScriptCS](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs)), or you can use languages like IronPython, IronRuby etc that run on the [DLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime).

Comment: I wouldn't particularly recommend it from personal experience, but if you really want to do this, you could look into [Dot Net Script](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6113/Dot-Net-Script)

Comment: @mason, right you are. But wouldn't that mean the users would have to write their 'scripts' in full-fledged c# code?

Comment: @TaW you can do C# by using Roslyn to compile, or run IronPython or IronRuby or others via DLR. The question doesn't specify what language. It just asks if it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but by using the [dynamic language runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd233052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .net you can integrate dynamic languages like [ruby](http://ironruby.net/) into your application. You could then write scripts in that language and interpret them in your app. I have used this to implement a plug-in system for one application, in which plug-ins (scripts) could be dynamically (at run-time) loaded into it without the need to recompile everything.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

- **Roslyn:** It's now possible to embed C# scripts using the [Roslyn scripting API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting). There are some [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) in the GitHub wiki to get you started.
- **DLR:** Scripting via the DLR is also possible. Here's an [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx) that illustrates how to run an IronPython script from inside your C# app. However, my (highly subjective) impression is that Roslyn is generating more developer interest than IronPython/DLR these days.